# python-sphinx automodule generates docs even for methods from third party modules

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I used automodule to generate documentation from docstrings, like the following:

```
.. automodule:: cdbus.csdb.chemnavi.db.schema
    :members:
```

But when using `:members:` it also generated documentation and example code for sqlalchemy, which is not in my module.  I just imported sqlalchemy to write my module.

[Screenshot of documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdlyo.png)

And this documentation is repeated every time I use the `members` keyword. How can I remove those additional docs and examples from sqlalchemy?

Comment: I think we need to know more about "cdbus" in order to explain what is happening. What does your code do? What exactly is the relation with SQLAlchemy? How can the problem be reproduced?

Comment: The package and file are too big so, I am explaining how it imports modules. cdbus is the module I am writing to make chemical database and use sqlalchemy. The base.py file in cdbus defines connection to mysql dbs and imports following libraries:

from sqlalchemy import and_, or_, not_
from sqlalchemy.types import BLOB as Blob
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
# All imports ar enot shown
In this module, there is a schema file at  cdbus/csdb/chemnavi/db/schema.py , which defines a mysql schema. It imports cdbus.base

Comment: There is still not enough information. How can the problem be reproduced?  Did you write any docstrings yourself? Do they show up in the output? In the screenshot, all the documentation that is shown comes from SQLAlchemy. If you have more details to add, please provide them by editing the question instead of adding comments.

Answer (score 1):

[automodule](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html?highlight=exclude-members#directive-automodule) has an option `exclude-members`:

```
.. automodule:: cdbus.csdb.chemnavi.db.schema
    :members:
    :exclude-members: this, that, other
```

Comment: So, every time after generating docs, I should check which additional docs were generated and I exclude them. But, isn't there any option to strictly not generate docs from imported modules?